# How can I show a .swf file?

Tags: flash

What is an easy way to show an `.swf` file in my homepage?

I have uploaded the `.swf` file in my uploads directory but I cannot show it via simple directive. What should I do to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

The below link would help in placing the swf file in your home page

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_object.asp

You could mention the path as /wp-content/uploads/your.swf
or you could use wp_upload_dir();

References : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir